# Angular directives and controller functions

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm using a ngRepeat div. Inside this div I'm assigning to directives such as ngClick, ngStyle and just expressions functions which belong to the controller.
Example:

```
<div ngStyle = "myCtrl.divStyle(key)"> ... </div>
```

When I'm updating the model this functions will not be called of course. How to force angular to call those functions. Is it a bad practice to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle

It is not clear what you are trying to do, but i think you can use pass a controller variable exposed via $scope .eg $scope.style to css style then on ngClick, change the value of $scope.style, if you want to use css class instead of inline styling, try ng-class.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle), the style is bound to the model. Changing the model will cause an update in the view.

```
<input type="button" value="set color" ng-click="myStyle={color:'red'}">
<span ng-style="myStyle">Sample Text</span>
```

And you can check out this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview) for a working example.